# (change) angular not after first element angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, file-upload

Good afternoon, I am implementing a simple image upload. I am facing one with a problem.

Problem scenario

1 - when selecting multiple files and adding them to a this.listFile list
2 - There is a method to remove an element through its index
3 - When I remove all the elements from the list, and redo the previous steps, the onChange () method no longer works.

Demo Project:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/upload-form?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

[image]

Demo Code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import {
  FormBuilder,
  FormGroup
} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public formCatalogSeller: FormGroup;
  public listFile: Array<any>;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.listFile = [];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initForm();
  }

  public removerFile(idx: string): void {
    const index = this.listFile.indexOf(this.listFile[idx]);
    if (index > -1) {
      this.listFile.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }

  public onChange(event) {
    const selectedFiles = <FileList>event.target.files;

    for (let i = 0; i < selectedFiles.length; i++) {
      this.listFile.push({ name: selectedFiles[i].name });
    }
  }

  private initForm(): void {
    this.formCatalogSeller = this.fb.group({
      images: []
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean bychange detection doesnt work, and can you share the code base, because you only shared the site part of your demo

Answer (score 0):

the solution to the problem was just to clean the input file

ex:

```
@ViewChild("inputFile") myInputVariable: ElementRef;

public removerFile(idx: string): void {
    const index = this.listFile.indexOf(this.listFile[idx]);
    if (index > -1) {
      this.listFile.splice(index, 1);
      this.myInputVariable.nativeElement.value = "";
    }
  }
```